# Excluding ASCII characters

Tags: python

I'm creating a palindrome checker and it works however I need to find a way to replace/remove punctuation from the given input. I'm trying to do for chr(i) i in range 32,47 then substitute those in with ''. The characters I need excluded are 32 - 47. I've tried using the String module but I can only get it to either exclude spaces or punctuation it can't be both for whatever reason.

I've already tried the string module but can't get that to remove spaces and punctuation at the same time.

```
def is_palindrome_stack(string):
    s = ArrayStack()
    for character in string:
    s.push(character)

    reversed_string = ''
while not s.is_empty():
    reversed_string = reversed_string + s.pop()

if string == reversed_string:
    return True
else:
    return False


def remove_punctuation(text):
    return text.replace(" ",'')
    exclude = set(string.punctuation)
    return ''.join(ch for ch in text if ch not in exclude)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Show what you've tried already and note what exactly about it didn't work and what you need help with.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Sorry everybody, I thought I had included that initially. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why are you doing `return text.replace(" ",'')` at the top? The two lines underneath it will never run. `return` causes the function to exit. I think you mean `text = text.replace(" ",'')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are returning from your method in the very first line, in `return text.replace(" ",'')`. Change it to `text =  text.replace(" ", "")` and it should work fine.

Also, the indentation is probably messed up in your post, maybe during copy pasting.

Full method snippet:

```
def remove_punctuation(text):
    text = text.replace(" ",'')
    exclude = set(string.punctuation)
    return ''.join(ch for ch in text if ch not in exclude)
```

Comment: indentation is definitely from copy and pasting. This solved my problem but now my palindrome is returning false when in fact it is not false.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `str` methods to get rid of unwanted characters following way:

```
import string
tr = ''.maketrans('','',' '+string.punctuation)
def remove_punctuation(text):
    return text.translate(tr)
txt = 'Point.Space Question?'
output = remove_punctuation(txt)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
PointSpaceQuestion
```

`maketrans` create replacement table, it accepts 3 `str`-s: first and second must be equal length, n-th character from first will be replaced with n-th character from second, third `str` is characters to remove. You need only to remove (not replace) characters so first two arguments are empty `str`s.